# T_STRING error at Curl

Tags: php, parse-error

When I'll upload my .php I get these error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /users/allybong/www/twitteroauth/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php on line 201
```

The script of line 197 - 231:

```
  function http($url, $method, $postfields = NULL) {
$this->http_info = array();
$ci = curl_init()
/* Curl settings */
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent)
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->connecttimeout)
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout)
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE)
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'))
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $this->ssl_verifypeer)
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array($this, 'getHeader'))
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE)

switch ($method) {
  case 'POST':
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    if (!empty($postfields)) {
      curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    }
    break;
  case 'DELETE':
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
    if (!empty($postfields)) {
      $url = "{$url}?{$postfields}";
    }
}

curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$response = curl_exec($ci);
$this->http_code = curl_getinfo($ci, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$this->http_info = array_merge($this->http_info, curl_getinfo($ci));
$this->url = $url;
curl_close ($ci);
return $response;
```

}

These is a script for a Twitter "BongBot". I get it from https://github.com/lizconlan/bongbot .

Comment: You are missing tons of semi colons after many lines

Comment: This question has nothing to do with cURL or Twitter. This is a PHP parser error.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt Twitter, no. cURL yes.

Comment: @njk This is a parser error, something that happens in PHP far before it even knows that it's going to use cURL. The `Parse error` part of the error code gives away that it has absolutely nothing to do with cURL.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of missing semicolons on the lines you pasted. That is probably the reason it gives you a `T_STRING` error.

Answer (score 3):

After and including the following line, none of your lines end with a semicolon:

```
$ci = curl_init()
```

Try adding one to the following lines and it should resolve your issue:

```
$ci = curl_init();
/* Curl settings */
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->connecttimeout);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $this->ssl_verifypeer);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array($this, 'getHeader'));
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
```

Comment: Hello! Now i get a "undefined function" at "curl_init" and "curl_setopt". But why?

Comment: @AUT_Markus Sounds like you don't have curl enabled in PHP. You'll have to make sure you have the extension installed and configured to use it.

Comment: Oh. I'm a idiot. :'D Thanks for all! :)

Comment: New Problem.
Now i get the error

    Warning: file_get_contents(last_update) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u124515119/public_html/schedule_me.php on line 12

Line:

    $last_tweet = explode(".", file_get_contents ("last_update"));

I don't know why...

Comment: @AUT_Markus Does the file `last_update` actually exist in the `/home/u124515119/public_html` directory? If not, there's your problem. If it does, it probably has permission problems; try updating it with `chmod 0774 last_update`.