# Why is PHP Curl returning T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING?

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm attempting to use PHP to get data from CallRail.com API via JSON.

However, I'm getting this error when previewing my PHP file directly in my browser: `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`

My code:

```
<?
curl -H "Authorization: Token token={my-token-id}" \
-X GET \
"https://api.callrail.com/v2/a/{my-account-id}/calls.json"
?>
```

So far I have:

- Read [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219070/t-string-error-at-curl) [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964924/what-causes-unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-string-error/34966787) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565768/php-syntax-error-unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-string) to the error without finding a solution or verifiably accurate explanation.
- I've manually retyped all of the code to ensure I didn't have any improperly encoded characters or invalid white spaces.
- I've also attempted to locate [official documentation in the PHP docs](http://php.net/results.php?q=T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING&l=en&p=all) but not found anything helpful.
- And I've tested this in a blank PHP file so the code is completely isolated.

**I don't know how to further debug this issue and am hoping someone can either identify the problem or share the steps to debug this on my own from this point.**

Comment: whats your full code?

Comment: And where is your php code?

Comment: That is my full code. It's in a single PHP file.

Comment: that's not php. it's for command line. @SpencerHill that's why you're getting a syntax error.

Comment: the above is command line curl, not php's curl.

Comment: Thank you @mim. Testing this from the command line returned my data.   For those who share my ignorance you can read the official PHP documentation on curl syntax here: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample is binary, to be executed from the command line in a shell like Bash, not PHP. This is why you're getting that error.

If you want PHP to call an external binary use `exec()`, `shell_exec()` or `system()`.

Also, for portability, don't use the `short open tags`, ever, because it depends on the `short_open_tag` php.ini directive, or whether or not PHP was compiled with `--enable-short-tags`.

Even if your code doesn't have to be portable, it's just a bad habit. In case you ever need to work with some portable PHP code in the future; try:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('curl -H "Authorization: Token token={my-token-id}" -X GET "https://api.callrail.com/v2/a/{my-account-id}/calls.json"');
```

Or if you want it on multiple lines, you could use implode:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec ( implode ( " ", [ 
        'curl',
        '-H "Authorization: Token token={my-token-id}"',
        '-X GET',
        '"https://api.callrail.com/v2/a/{my-account-id}/calls.json"' 
] ) );
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. As I understand it, "binary" simply refers to any and all code. So don't you mean "bash"? Also, I don't know what short open tags are, or how it's relevant. Can you clarify in your Answer?